# How to use MouseMotionListner in GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am making a Tetris game and want to use `MouseMotionListener` in grid area (i.e. when the cursor goes inside the main area it should pause). But it's not working in the `gridLayout` field. However, `MouseWheelListener` is working there. At the same time, it's working for the other right side panel but not in the main area.

```
MouseMotionListener mml= new MouseMotionAdapter()
{
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me)
      {
          System.out.println("mouse moved");
          pauseGame();
      }
};
```

and

```
this.addMouseMotionListener(mml);
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
this.add(game_grid);
this.add(right_panel);
this.setBackground(bg_color);
this.validate();
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Try this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/event/mousemotionevent-example/ This is great link full description on mousemotionlistner

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  My first guess is that things are being added to that component, that block the mouse events passing to the 'parent' that has the listener, but post an SSCCE & I can be sure.

Comment: Do you have other mouse listeners attached to the other components?

Comment: @madprogrammer : Yes I have MouseMotionListner and MouseWheelListener to the right side panels since they are serving for rotating and shifting the blocks of tetris.

Comment: These components will block the mouse listener on you base container

Comment: it worked by just doing    `game_grid.addMouseMotionListener(mml);`